# Creating a random string results in just duplicate strings c++

Tags: c++, debugging, random

So i have tried using rand(), and random but it results in the same problem each time, all strings created are duplicate. I think the problem may come from the number generator but i have no idea.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<time.h>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

int count;
char letter;
string word;
char ls[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 51); 

string code()
{
   for (int i = dis(gen) ; count != 13; count++){
        word += ls[i];
        i = dis(gen); 
    }
    return word;

}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    while(true){       
        cout << code() <<"\n";
        srand(time(0));
    }
    sleep(10);

    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = dis(gen) ; count != 13; count++){
```

The first time your code calls this function, this `for` loop will count this up until this `count` reaches 13. This is fairly simple, and basic.

But you will be surprised to learn that the second time your code calls this function, `count` is still what it was last time: 13. Why should it be anything else? After all, nothing in the code changed it, between the first and the second call to this function. So this `for` loop does absolutely nothing, whatsoever. `count` is already 13.

Furthermore, the first time this function was called, the random letters get accumulated in `word`. Guess what? This `word` is still exactly the same. After all, nothing changed `word` or cleared it.

So this function doesn't do anything the 2nd time it gets called, and it simply returns the same `word`. And it does the same thing every time it's called. That's why you always get the same string, every time.

What you need to do is remember The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do". If you would like your computer to always start counting here with 0, and put the randomly-generated letters into a new word, every time this function is called: then this is exactly what you need to tell your computer to do. The simplest solution is to simply declare `count` and `word` as local to this function, and explicitly initialize `count` to 0 (instead of having them as global variables). It is a pretty popular rule of thumb in C++: the more global variables there are, the more opportunities for bugs exist.

Oh, and the shown code needs to call `srand` exactly once. It may or may not do anything, in the shown code, but repeatedly calling `srand` only makes things worse, and not better.

Comment: To OP: Here's a corrected and simplified version of the code following the advice in this answer (and some other tweaks): [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fWjcEe). Note: `srand` isn't allowed to have an effect on the rest of the code in the question at all (as per the c++ standard) - so, just remove it.